# Android popup on activity create

Tags: java, android, android-activity, popup

I am using the following code to create a popup which shows as the activity loads. 
I call loadingPopup(); in my oncreate method.
The popup works the problem is when ever i try to place onclick listener for the dismiss button the whole thing crashes on load. If i were to remove the DissMissButton onclick listener code it works fine. Any help would be appreciated

```
 private void loadingPopup() {
       LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
       final View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_welcome, null);
       final Button DismissButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_welcomepopup_dismiss);
       final PopupWindow Welcome_popupWindow = new PopupWindow(layout, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);

       Welcome_popupWindow.setFocusable(false);
       Welcome_popupWindow.setTouchable(true);
       Welcome_popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);

       layout.post(new Runnable() {

           public void run() {
               Welcome_popupWindow.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
               DismissButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {
                       Welcome_popupWindow.dismiss();
                   }
               });
           }

       });
```

Answer (score 0):

You call find view on your activity view, while your button is in the popup, so of course the `DismissButton` is null and app force close.
Change the find view code to this:

```
       final Button DismissButton = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.button_welcomepopup_dismiss);
```

Comment: Doh! i knew it was bound to be something stupid...happens when you been staring at the screen too long